# Can't figure out what's wrong with my domain object design

Tags: java, class, oop, domain-driven-design, domain-object

I have this 2 classes, and someone told me that I did it wrong.

```
class Employee {
private int employeeID;
private String employeeName;
private Seat employeeSeat;
}
```

This is for my employee class which has a relationship with the Seat class

```
class Seat {
private int seatID;
private String seatCode;
private Employee occupant;
}
```

I also added an employee attribute to my seat because when I retrieve the seat, I want to determine who is the current occupant of the seat. Same thing with my employee, when I retrieve it, I want to determine the employee's current seat. Now, they said that because the employee has a seat attribute, and the seat has an employee attribute, it's a terrible design.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to ask the person that told you it was wrong to explain in detail what they mean.  It may or may not be, but that would depend on the overall system architecture and requirements for navigating between objects.

Likely what they mean is that you should have an `EmployeeSeat` object to hold the relationship and any details pertaining to that relationship (start date, end date, hours, whatever).  But then you have to worry about other problems like enforcing cardinality constraints (can an employee have multiple seats, or vice versa)?

Comment: I guess that's what he meant more or less, but my problem if I did that is if I add another attribute Project to my employee class that references to Project class like the employee-seat, and I want to display the employees together with their project and seat, that becomes a problem.

Comment: It's not a "problem", it's a "tradeoff" between complexity and requirements.  This is what Software Engineering is about, in a nutshell.  Real-world tradeoffs that you have to make constantly.  This why design is hard, and it's not something you learn in school (unless you have some stellar professors).

Comment: So I was wondering if I would have to create a class to link Seat and Project to the Employee like EmployeeSeatProject or stuff, or is it better to just put it as attributes in the employee class.

Comment: "SeatAssignment" is probably more in keeping with the ubiquitous language.

Answer (score 0):

Because the risk of updating one side of the relationship at runtime to point to another entity and forgetting to update the other side (leaving the model in an inconsistent state) is generally considered way worse than the slight inconvenience of working with a one-direction association. It's not always possible though.

Comment: Isn't just that it breaks aggregate boundaries to reference an AR within another AR?

Comment: Could also be, but the OP doesn't mention aggregates. Evans talks about bidirectional associations between entities in the blue book regardless of aggregates if I remember correctly.

Comment: True, but that was in the ages where leveraging the domain model to produce queries was still recommended. That is basically the only reason you need to reference an AR within another.

Comment: But we could also be talking about two entities referencing each other inside the same aggregate ;)